# platform-independent version of trellis.device(device="windows",...)

Tags: r, lattice

Is there a platform-independent way of arraying lattice plots for screen output?

My approach involves using:

```
trellis.device(device="windows")
print(chart.hist, split = c(1,1,1,2), more = TRUE)
print(chart.cdf, split = c(1,2,1,2))
```

On my mac, i need `trellis.device(device="x11",...)`, on my windows machine at work I need `trellis.device(device="windows",...)`

an example:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)

discrete.cdf <- function(x, decreasing=FALSE){
    x <- x[order(x,decreasing=FALSE)]
    result <- data.frame(rank=1:length(x),x=x)
    result$cdf <- result$rank/nrow(result)
    return(result)
}

my.df <- discrete.cdf(x)

chart.hist <- histogram(~x, data=my.df,
                        xlab="")
chart.cdf <- xyplot(100*cdf~x, data=my.df, type="s",
                    ylab="Cumulative Percent of Total")

graphics.off()
trellis.device(device = "windows", width = 6, height = 6)
print(chart.hist, split = c(1,1,1,2), more = TRUE)
print(chart.cdf, split = c(1,2,1,2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just omit the option "device" to the `trellis.device()` function. It will take the platform-specific default (at least it works like that here on Linux, with "x11" being the default device).